# ASP Classic Programming With FirstData GGe4

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, firstdata

Has anyone out there developed a UI for interaction with the FirstData GGe4 using ASP Classic/VBScript/JavaScript?  I've been working for days and have been nothing but spinning my wheels.

Any help would be MUCH appreciated!,
Thank You,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

I have integrated FirstData's API for card processing into my ASP CMS.
Here are the three relevant ASP files:
http://www.oceanmedia.net/files/HK-FirstData.zip.
Note the one called "i_firstdata_proc.asp". 
That is a file I got from FirstData BUT I probably made some changes to it so please just be aware of that.
Hope this helps!
Scott